# MySQL/PHP SUM data in an ARRAY

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT AVG (q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG (q3) AS q3 
FROM thotels_results 
WHERE brand IN ('ABC','EFG','XYZ') 
AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand;
```

I `LOOP` through the results and have dumped out the array using `var_dump`, the output is below:

```
array
  'q1' => string '8.1724' (length=6)
  'q2' => string '8.2414' (length=6)
  'q3' => string '8.2414' (length=6)

array
  'q1' => string '8.7714' (length=6)
  'q2' => string '8.8429' (length=6)
  'q3' => string '8.1643' (length=6)

array
  'q1' => string '8.6009' (length=6)
  'q2' => string '8.5686' (length=6)
  'q3' => string '7.8528' (length=6)
```

What I would like to do is, somehow, add each of the q1's together and divide by 3 to give me an average, then the same for q2 and the same for q3:

```
8.1724 + 8.7714 + 8.6009 / 3 = 8.5149
```

I'm not sure how to access the information stored in the array - thanks in advance.

Homer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before loop start

```
$q1sum=0;
$q2sum=0;
$q3sum=0;
$count=0
```

put this inside the loop you traversed.

```
$q1sum+=(float) $array['q1'] ;
$q2sum+=(float) $array['q2'] ;
$q3sum+=(float) $array['q3'] ;
$count++;
```

put this out of the loop after the loop end.

```
$q1final_result=$q1sum/$count;
$q2final_result=$q2sum/$count;
$q3final_result=$q3sum/$count;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$q1Ave = $q2Ave = $q3Ave = 0
foreach ($results as $qValues) {
   $q1Ave += $qValues['q1'];
   $q2Ave += $qValues['q2'];
   $q3Ave += $qValues['q3'];
}
$q1Ave /= count($results);
$q2Ave /= count($results);
$q3Ave /= count($results);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try
`SELECT SUM(q1)/3 as q1, SUM(q2)/3 as q2, SUM(q3)/3 as q3

 FROM (

        SELECT AVG (q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG (q3) AS q3

        FROM thotels_results

        WHERE brand IN ('ABC','EFG','XYZ')

        AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand
) as derived_table;`

Comment: Hi, tried that but getting the following error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Sorry for that. I just added an alis for derived table called `as derived_table`

Comment: Perfect!  Very very elegant answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
$tab = array(
                 0 => array ("q1" => 2,"val2" => 5),
                 1 => array ("q1" => 6,"val2" => 10),
                 2 => array ("q1" => 15,"val2" => 50),
                );

echo sum_subarrays_by_key( $tab, "q1" );



function sum_subarrays_by_key( $tab, $key ) {

        $sum = 0;

        foreach($tab as $sub_array) {
            $sum += $sub_array[$key];
        }

        return $sum;

    }
```

It will work at every depth of array. need to call by changing key which u want to sum in calling function